# Controlling hardware through C

Tags: c

I want to control hardware using C language (ANSI/Standard C). I am not asking about interfacing. I want to manage my computer resources by C code. like how can I eject my DVD ROM drive. a code that produces a beep from speaker. and similar things. 
I need a good tutorial, or any study material which is free.

Comment: That's not possible with just standard C.  You'll need at least some kind of system-specific support library.

Comment: Try googling "eject cd rom drive programmatically" - there is a lot of help.

Comment: Hardware is platform dependent. You can control some hardware on the (for example) PC platform using direct I/O to hardware ports (`outport()` and `inport()`), but most operative systems won't let you do direct I/O for security reasons, and expose instead hardware abstraction functions. One doesn't simply "control hardware using C".

Comment: This would really depend on your platform, operating system and other such low level details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic entry point of hardware input/output control is [`ioctl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) (or `DeviceIoControl` on Windows, described on the same Wikipedia article).

Comment: It's a UNIX specific thing really. There are equivalents in most OSs but it's not really universal.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim - You are correct. Unix-like platforms are so widespread on our desks and in our pockets that I always forget Windows.

Comment: @SyedaAmnaAhmed - Sure it is possible: ioctl is written in C. The underlying code involve reading and writing specific data to specific memory addresses. You will need data sheets of your hardware components.